# SWT Text widget does not show up

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, layout, swt

I'm trying to have "Hello SWT" show up in the center of a window in SWT, but nothing is showing.

[image: empty window]

Here is my simple code (scala.version=2.9.0-1, swt:3.7.0-win32):

```
package org.jilen.editor
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT

object EditorApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val display = new Display()
    val shell = new Shell(display)
    val text = new Text(shell, SWT.CENTER)
    text.setText("Hello SWT")
    shell.pack()
    shell.open()
    while (!shell.isDisposed) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch) {
        display.sleep()
      }
    }
    display.dispose()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line after creating your shell:

```
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout)
```

Comment: That's it! it seems "swt/jface in action" is too old for swt 3.7

Comment: Actually, it's always been like this.  :-)  It's simply the difference between SWT (which has no default layout) and JFace (which does).